# two inequalities involving integral

Tags: integration, inequality, multiple-integral

I was wondering if the following inequality implies the other.

I have 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\int_0^{v_0}\mathbf{1}_{\{v\geq p\}}dvdw>\int_0^1\int_0^{v_0}\mathbf{1}_{\{v+x_w\geq p'\}}\,dv\,dw,
\end{equation}
where $p$ and $p'$ are two different positive constants and $x_w$ is a non-negative function of $w$.

So basically, I am computing the probability (or just counting) of two events and the above inequality implies that the left is greater than the right.

Now I am wondering if the above inequality implies the following one
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\int_0^{v_0}\mathbf{1}_{\{v\geq p\}}(v-p)\,dv\,dw>\int_0^1\int_0^{v_0}\mathbf{1}_{\{v+x_w\geq p'\}}(v+x_w-p')\,dv\,dw,
\end{equation}
I think intuitively it should be correct, but I am not so sure. Can someone prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've miscalculated, the first inequality doesn't imply the second.

Let's be very concrete. Take $v_0=1$, $p=\frac12$, $p'=\frac23$, and $x_w=\frac w3$. Then the integrals in the first inequality are *equal*, so a tiny perturbation will make the first inequality hold.

For the LHS of the second inequality we can ignore the integral over $w$ for the obvious reason; then we have $\int_p^{v_0}(v-p)\,dv=\frac12(v_0-p)^2=\frac18$. For the RHS we have $\int_0^1 dw\int_{p'-x_w}^{v_0}(v+x_w-p')\,dv=\int_0^1dw\frac12(v_0+x_w-p')^2\,dv=\int_0^1dw\frac12(\frac{1+w}3)^2$ which equals $\frac16\cdot3\cdot[(\frac23)^3-(\frac13)^3]=\frac7{54}$ and this is *bigger* than $\frac7{56}=\frac18$. So the second inequality fails when the first is right on the edge, and a tiny perturbation will not change that.

(This is really about the convexity of the function mapping $x$ to $x^2$. The values at $w$ and $1-w$ average to more than the value at $w=\frac12$.)

Comment: Nice example. So if we want the 1st inequality to imply the 2nd inequality, what conditions should we impose on $x_w$ or on $p$ and $p'$?